# position fixed with placeholder

Tags: css, height, css-position

I have a div with dynamic height.
This div needs to be position: fixed.
The following div should vertically start where the first div ends.

The reason is that the div is a header that should stay on top. However, the content should start right after the header. So that when the page is scrolled the header stays fixed and the rest scrolls as usual. Setting a margin-top for the content usually does the trick but this type the header has a dynamic height. Any ideas?

EDIT: One solution I could think of is printing the header twice and setting the second to position: relative and visibility: hidden. While it should work it seems a terrible solution.

Comment: Why is the height dynamic?

Comment: The height is dynamic because the layout is responsive. Also, there is no code to speak of. Just one header div and one for content.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed and absolutely positioned elements are outside the normal page flow. You cannot set other content relative to and outside them with CSS alone.

Here's a Fiddle in case anyone wants to, erm, fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/fX7cH/1/

```
<div id="page">
  <div id="header"></div>
  <div id="content"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this specific case was defining different margin-top values for the content div for the respective stylesheets (desktop, mobile). This is however, not a general solution. The problem was that the menu in the mobile layout had each list item in a block display. So, depending on the number of items the margin-top of the content div needed to be adjusted manually. Not exactly elegant, but works for me.

Answer (score 0):

I've struggled with this for a while, and although not perfect, here's a different solution that uses whatever dynamic content goes into the header again as a placeholder to get the exact same height, then uses CSS to visually hide the content and the `aria-hidden="true"` HTML attribute to hide from screen readers. No messing with margins here.

https://jsfiddle.net/lukehatfield/zmcj3htx/

```
<div class="page">
  <div class="header">HEADER</div>
  <div class="header-placeholder" aria-hidden="true">HEADER</div>
  <div class="content">CONTENT</div>
</div>
```